# MultiValueDictKeyError at /connect/

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to have all location functionality on one page, such as
`get users location`, `post it to the database`, then `filter results` based on a user-inputted kilometre radius value.

I am getting `MultiValueDictKeyError at /connect/ 'latitude'` because the POST request is going to

```
location = Location(latitude=request.POST['latitude'], longitude=request.POST['longitude'], user = request.user)
```

when it should be going to

```
if request.POST['radius']:
            radius_km = request.POST.get('radius', 0)
```

I researched how to stop this happening and saw I could do `if request.POST['radius']:` to direct the post request to the right function.

This hasn't helped with the error unfortunately.

Am I missing something?

views.py

```
class ConnectView(View):
    template_name = 'connect/home.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        f = ProfileFilter(request.GET, queryset=Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user))
        context = {
            'users': User.objects.exclude(username=request.user),
            'friends': Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user),
            'filter': f,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        location = Location(latitude=request.POST['latitude'], longitude=request.POST['longitude'], user = request.user)
        location.save()
        if request.POST['radius']:
            radius_km = request.POST.get('radius', 0)
            queryset = User.objects.annotate(
                radius_sqr=pow(models.F('loc__latitude') -
                request.user.loc.latitude, 2) + pow(models.F('loc__longitude') -
                request.user.loc.longitude, 2)
                ).filter(
                radius_sqr__lte=pow(int(radius_km) / 9, 2)
                ).exclude(username=request.user)
            context = {'users': queryset}
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'success'})
```

home.html

```
<script>
  var pos;

  var $demo;

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      $demo.text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    pos = position;
    var { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
    $('#btn_submit').attr("disabled", null);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $demo = $("#demo");
    $('#btn_submit').on('click', function() {
      var data = pos.coords;
      data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
      $.post('', data, function() {
        alert("Location Confirmed!");
      });
    });
  });

</script>

      <h1>Connect with people.</h1>

            <!-- GET window.location IP Address / lat lon coordinates -->
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <button onclick="getLocation()" class="btn btn-warning" id="confirm">1. Find Location</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit"  class="btn btn-success" disabled>2. Submit Location </button>

            <!-- filter by profile attributes -->
            <form method="GET">
                {{ filter.form }}
                <button type="submit" class="small">Search.</button>
            </form>

            <!-- enter radius to filter by location-->
            <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="number" name="radius">
              <input type="submit" value="filter by kilometers">
            </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it should be going to...". Your code executes line by line and if the first line throws an exception it's not going to skip it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` is just a python dictionary (almost, it can have multiple values for the same key, hence the class name `MultiValueDict`). So just treat it as a normal dictionary object:

- `dict[key]` raises a `KeyError` if the `key` doesn't exist
- `dict.get(key)` returns the value for `key` or `None` if it doesn't exist.
- `dict.get(key, default)` returns the value for `key` of `default` if the `key` doesn't exist.

`request.POST['latitude']`, `request.POST['longitude']` and `request.POST['radius']` will throw this exception if these keys aren't in the POST parameters. Always use `request.POST.get(param_name)` when checking what is being submitted.

In your case, you should also add an `if 'latitude' in request.POST and 'longitude' in request.POST` clause before doing anything with `latitude` and `longitude`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you are saying that the `request.POST.get('')` will first check which post request is being submitted? I've tried adding `request.POST.get('latitude', 'longitude')` and 'request.POST.get('radius)` but I still get the same error.

Comment: No. `request.POST` is just a python dictionary. See my update. You might want to do a python tutorial to understand this properly, this has nothing to do with Django. `request.POST.get('latitude', 'longitude')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I am a beginner so I appreciate your patience. Would `request.POST.get()` go before the `location = Location` variable? How do I add `radius, lat, lon` to the POST parameters along with an if clause to check whether `lat lon` has already been satisfied?

Comment: Something like `request.POST.get("radius", "") == 'radius'` ?

Comment: just add `if 'latitude' in request.POST and 'longitude' in request.POST:` before defining and saving `location`. Then `if 'radius' in request.POST:` (instead of `if request.POST['radius']` which crashes if there's no radius)

Comment: Hi Dirk, I've just watched a python video and implemented `try:` before `location` and `except:` before `if request,POST` which gave me the same result as implementing what you said above. Which is the preferred method?

Comment: `try: except:` should be used only for catching a specific exception, so yes, you could do `try:... except MultiValueDictKeyError:` (be sure to add the type of exception, `location.save()` might also throw a different exception and you don't want to catch that!). But `if: ...` or `if: ... else: ...` of `if: ... elif: ...` is much easier to read and makes it clearer what the intended flow is. Exceptions should be as their name says: exceptions. Not the main flow. Best practice is readable code and in this case `if ...`

Answer (score 2):

In your post method, you have added `request.POST['latitude']`, which you might not be passing with the post method. And your `if..` condition comes after that. Therefore Django gives you error, because it doesn't find any parameter with this name, and will stop the further execution.

So, on post request if you are not passing latitude longitude parameters try writting it as:

`request.POST.get('latitude', None)`

or,

put your `if..` condition before accessing `latitude` and `longitutde` parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The `request.POST['latitude 
/ longitude']` is passed to the `location` variable when the user presses the `btn-submit` first. Then `lat lon` should get used in the `radius` queryset. I have swapped the `if...` condition to go before, but I still get the error.

Comment: In short I am trying to handle different values from a post request.